# indexPath is nil when passing cell from delegate to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a button called addSet at the end of each section of my tableView, it is used as a footerView and it is supposed to tell the UITableViewController of when it is pressed and in which section. My code for the custom table view cell is as follows

```
import UIKit

class FooterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }

    var footerDelegate:FooterTableViewCellDelegate?

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }



    @IBAction func addSetIsPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        print("Add Set is pressed")

        footerDelegate?.didAddSetIsPressed(cell:self)
    }



}

protocol FooterTableViewCellDelegate {

    func didAddSetIsPressed(cell:FooterTableViewCell)
}
```

And in my TableViewController, I implement it like so

```
func didAddSetIsPressed(cell: FooterTableViewCell) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

    print("Index path is \(indexPath)")
}
```

I want to get the indexPath (the section specifically) when the user taps my button, however it always returns nil. What am I doing wrong?

To put things in context. I am using this cell as a footerView, so the cell is implemented like so

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "footerCell") as! FooterTableViewCell
    cell.footerDelegate = self


    return cell
}
```

so it isn't implemented in cellForRow at indexPath like it would normally be

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you put the cell `FooterTableViewCell` as a `viewForFooterInSection`,
so **it's not used as a** `UITableViewCell` **in the** `UITableView`, so the `UITableView` is not holding the `indexPath` of this `UITableViewCell` "Cause i said previously, the cell's view only is used as a **footerView**"

You need to add the button inside the cell that's being rendered on the `UITableView`. "The one that's being returned in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method"

> On a side note i noticed that you have a variable named `footerDelegate` in your cell, it needs to be `weak` to avoid memory leaks as you assign your `TableViewController` as this delegate,
>    so the `UITableViewCell` holds a strong reference of the `TableViewController` that leads to memory leak cause also in the view hierarchy the `TableViewController` contains the `UITableView` as a subView.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I am already using the function cellForRow at indexPath with my cells that must be displayed in each section, so how can I use this function for both my rows and my footer?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it, in order to detect the section in which the button was tapped. There must be an outlet reference in the FooterCell and in the tableViewController, in viewForFooter in Section, just add the following line

```
cell.addSetOutlet.tag = section
```